# Binding element 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I've been working on trying to learn and understand Nextjs and TypeScript by trying to build a Navbar by using a tutorial article (https://www.mikealche.com/software-development/learn-react-animations-by-creating-a-stripe-inspired-menu).

Despite the fact the menu items seem to be working locally and the underline animation comes in and follow the mouse hover (this is as far as I've gotten in the article) I am still getting the following problems:

1. MenuItem.tsx

   - Binding element 'text' implicitly has an 'any' type. ts(7031) [6,21]
   - Binding element 'children' implicitly has an 'any' type. ts(7031) [6,27]
2. SubItem.tsx

   - Parameter 'title' implicitly has an 'any' type. ts(7006) [4,18]
   - Parameter 'text' implicitly has an 'any' type. ts(7006) [4, 25]
3. SubItemContainer.tsx

   - Binding element 'children' implicitly has an 'any' type. ts(7031) [3,29]

I'm still pretty new with React, NextJs and TypeScript but have slowly been going through the docs, the vids, and having patience in learning. However I am not too sure how to fix this, or find a way to better mitigate this from happening in the future.

I've gone ahead and posted the files below.

Thanks for any help on this or suggestions.

**Navbar.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import MenuItem from "./MenuItem";
import SubItem from "./SubItem";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="w-screen p-20">
      <motion.div className="flex justify-center p-10 border">
        <MenuItem text={"Home"}>
          <SubItem title="Product" text="A SaaS for e-commerce" />
          <SubItem title="Blog" text="Latest posts" />
          <SubItem title="Contact" text="Get in touch" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem text={"About"} style={{ minWidth: 400 }}>
          <SubItem title="The Team" text="Get to know us better" />
          <SubItem title="The Company" text="Since 1998" />
          <SubItem
            title="Our Mission"
            text="Increase the GDP of the internet"
          />
          <SubItem title="Investors" text="who's backing us" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem text={"Products"} style={{ minWidth: 400 }}>
          <SubItem
            title="Ecommerce"
            text="Unify online and in-person payments"
          />
          <SubItem
            title="Marketplaces"
            text="Pay out globally and facilitate multiparty payments"
          />
          <SubItem
            title="Platforms"
            text="Let customers accept payments within your platform"
          />
          <SubItem
            title="Creator Economy"
            text="Facilitate on-platform payments and pay creators globally"
          />
        </MenuItem>
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

**MenuItem.tsx**

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { useState } from "react";
import Underline from "./Underline";
import SubItemContainer from "./SubItemContainer";

const MenuItem = ({ text, children, ...props }) => {
  const [isBeingHovered, setIsBeingHovered] = useState(false);

  return (
    <motion.div
      className="relative px-10 cursor-pointer"
      onHoverStart={() => setIsBeingHovered(true)}
      onHoverEnd={() => setIsBeingHovered(false)}
    >
      <span className="relative">
        {text}
        {isBeingHovered && <Underline />}
      </span>
      {isBeingHovered && <SubItemContainer>{children}</SubItemContainer>}
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default MenuItem;
```

**SubItem.tsx**

```
import { Hashicon } from "@emeraldpay/hashicon-react";
import React from "react";

const SubItem = (title, text) => {
  return (
    <div className="my-2 cursor-pointer group min-w-max">
      <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
        <Hashicon value={title} size={25} />
        <div className="">
          <p className="font-bold text-gray-800 group-hover:text-blue-900 text-md">
            {title}
          </p>
          <span className="text-sm font-bold text-gray-400 group-hover:text-blue-400">
            {text}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SubItem;
```

**SubItemContainer.tsx**

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const SubItemContainer = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="py-5 min-w-max">
      <motion.div
        layoutId="menu"
        className="absolute border border-1 shadow-lg py-10 px-10 bg-white rounded-box -left-2/4"
        style={{ minWidth: 400 }}
        initial="hiddens"
        animate="visible"
      >
        {children}
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SubItemContainer;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While typescript is able to infer types most of the time, it cannot do it for react props, even for children props.

To remove all the `XXX implicitly has an 'any' type` in your code, you need to add a `React.FC` (stands for Functional Component) for your components using `children` and `React.FC<ComponentProps>` when using your own props.

For your three current component you would have:

**MenuItem.tsx**

```js
[...]

// Define your component props
type MenuItemProps = {
  text: string;
  // ...rest of your props
}

// Add props
const MenuItem: React.FC<MenuItemProps> = ({ text, children, ...props }) => {

[...]
```

**SubItem.tsx**

```js
[...]

// Define your component props
type SubItemProps = {
  title: string;
  text: string;
}

// Add props and fix your code as props is the first parameter
const SubItem: React.FC<SubItemProps> = ({ title, text }) => {

[...]
```

**SubItemContainer.tsx**

```js
[...]

// Only add React.FC 
const SubItemContainer: React.FC = ({ children }) => { type

[...]
```

Comment: Thanks P.E.

I'm getting a couple of new errors now after fixing the initial problem.

Navbar.tsx
  Type '{ children: Element[]; text: string; style: { minWidth: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IMenuItem & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'style' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IMenuItem & { children?: ReactNode; }'.

SubMenuItem.tsx (formerly SubItem.tsx)
  No overload matches this call. ts(2769) [9, 19]

Comment: Where I put "// ...rest of your props" you should add the missing props that you are expecting when spreading props. Seems to be missing `style?: CSSProperties | undefined`. You need to import CSSProperties from react.

Comment: Thanks again - I missed that part completely, and was able to sort out the style problem.

Comment: Pretty sure, Tailwind should not impact in any way your type definition. Nevertheless if you need to send your class names to a component remember to add `className: string;` to its props type. If you run into any typescript issue due to Tailwind I would be interested to know about it: link any StackOverflow question you ask in this thread and I will check them.